# Vb.net filter date on datagridview

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datagridview, datetimepicker

I am coding using vb.net and using access. I have a datagridview with, and I want to create a button that will filter my dgv by the date that the user will choose using datetimepicker. I tried to do this, but it seems that it does not read.

```
Private Sub CmdOk_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdOk.Click

        s = "Select * from tblQuestion 
Where tblQuestion.IDRespondent = " & Me.UcSayDoctor.TextBox.Text & " 
OR tblQuestion.ID_Customer = " & Me.UcSayCustomer.TextBox.Text & " 
OR tblQuestion.Date =  " & (FormatDateTime(dateFilter.Value, DateFormat.ShortDate)) & ""
        retVal = getRS(s, rs, False, sErro)

        If retVal Then
            da.Fill(ds, rs, "tblQuestion")
            mainForm.gridQuestion.DataSource = (ds.Tables("tblQuestion"))
        End If
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub
```

The first two part of "where" is working well. 
But i think I am coding wrong using datetimepicker since I am new to this style.

```
OR tblQuestion.Date =  " & (FormatDateTime(dateFilter.Value, DateFormat.ShortDate)) & ""
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Slai It did not work. Just a question, with this code you just told me, am I passing the value datetimepicker to a string? because on access it is not as a text, it is as date/time. I forgot to say that, sorry

Comment: @Slai ooh! It worked, thanks for the help, and also the source with the info! Thanks a lot

Comment: @Slai just to mention I did like this #" & (FormatDateTime(dateFilter.Value, DateFormat.ShortDate)) & "#". Thank you so much. I just cannot upvote your answer :(

Comment: You can accept @Slai 's answer by clicking the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer. This is the best way to thank someone for their answer.

Answer (score 1):

Dates in Access queries have to be surrounded by hashtags. For example `= #12/31/2018#` https://support.office.com/en-us/article/examples-of-using-dates-as-criteria-in-access-queries-aea83b3b-46eb-43dd-8689-5fc961f21762

In your case :

```
OR tblQuestion.Date = #" & dateFilter.Value.ToString("m/d/yyyy") & "#"
```

Answer (score 0):

Date should be in a string format and must be encoded in single quotes. In your last line add single quotes before and after date

```
    s = "Select * from tblQuestion Where tblQuestion.IDRespondent = " & Me.UcSayDoctor.TextBox.Text & " OR tblQuestion.ID_Customer = " & Me.UcSayCustomer.TextBox.Text & " OR tblQuestion.Date =  " & "'" & FormatDateTime(dateFilter.Value, DateFormat.ShortDate) & "'"
```